# D3 v6 how to join correctly?

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm new to D3, and most of the examples I'm finding are for v3. Trying to update a code to use the join pattern, but can't get it working. It goes something like this:

```
[...]

let link = svg.append("g").attr("class", "links").selectAll("path");
let node = svg.append("g").selectAll("g");

function update() {
  node = node
    .data(nodes)
    .join("g", enter => {
      enter
        // Add some stuff...
        .call(drag(simulation)); // This does not work. If I put the call(drag(... after the join it works.
    });
}

[...]
```

What am I doing wrong with the call method?

Answer (score 1):

`selection.join()` has three function arguments: `enter, update, exit`. You need to put all your code in the `enter` function, without the first argument: using a string as a first argument works [only if you're only appending that element](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_join) and not doing any extra tasks:

```
node = node
    .data(nodes)
    .join("g") // will only append "g" in the enter selection, can't do anything else
```

Instead, you can append directly in the enter selection:

```
function update() {
  node = node
    .data(nodes)
    .join(enter => {
      enter
        .append("g")
        // Add some stuff...
        .call(drag(simulation)); // This does not work. If I put the call(drag(... after the join it works.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [recommended usage of join](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join)

> The return value of the enter and update function is important—it
> specifies the selections to merge and return by selection.join.

You aren't returning anything from your enter function. The following should work. The enter selection is returned (note the lack of curly braces) as it's used by join for DOM updates:

```
[...]

let link = svg.append("g").attr("class", "links").selectAll("path");
let node = svg.append("g").selectAll("g");

function update() {
  node = node
    .data(nodes)
    .join("g", enter => 
      enter
        .call(drag(simulation))
    );
}

[...]
```